# Selenium & WebDriver for Chrome not working on JupyterLab (Mac)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, selenium-chromedriver, jupyter-lab

**Background:**
I'm trying to use Selenium on my Mac to scrape a recipe website, but am having issues initializing Chrome WebDriver, with Selenium. I downloaded chromedriver (both the Windows and Mac versions) and it's in the same dir as the JupyterNotebook file:
[image]

**Code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import selenium
import time
import csv
import os
import sys

driver=webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
url = "https://www.simplyrecipes.com/index/"
driver.get(url) 
response=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
```

**Error:**

```
driver---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/envs/DataScience/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py in start(self)
     75                                             stderr=self.log_file,
---> 76                                             stdin=PIPE)
     77         except TypeError:

~/anaconda3/envs/DataScience/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors, text)
    799                                 errread, errwrite,
--> 800                                 restore_signals, start_new_session)
    801         except:

~/anaconda3/envs/DataScience/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, restore_signals, start_new_session)
   1550                             err_msg += ': ' + repr(err_filename)
-> 1551                     raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
   1552                 raise child_exception_type(err_msg)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'chromedriver': 'chromedriver'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-130893dfba7a> in <module>
      1 #set up chromedriver
----> 2 =web.Chrome('chromedriver')
      3 url = "https://www.simplyrecipes.com/index/"
      4 .get(url)
      5 response=requests.get(url)

~/anaconda3/envs/DataScience/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py in __init__(self, executable_path, port, options, service_args, desired_capabilities, service_log_path, chrome_options, keep_alive)
     71             service_args=service_args,
     72             log_path=service_log_path)
---> 73         self.service.start()
     74 
     75         try:

~/anaconda3/envs/DataScience/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py in start(self)
     81                 raise WebDriverException(
     82                     "'%s' executable needs to be in PATH. %s" % (
---> 83                         os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
     84                 )
     85             elif err.errno == errno.EACCES:

WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
driverdriver
```

**Help:**
I have read the [documentation](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home) and am pretty sure I have everything set, so I just can't understand where I'm going wrong.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Even if your Juypternote is in the same path as chrome driver, you still have to specify the path -

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from splinter import Browser
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import selenium
import time
import csv
driver=webdriver.Chrome("/Users/williamforsyth/Documents/homeworks/Homework_Repos/group-project-2/Kathryn/chromedriver")
url = "https://www.simplyrecipes.com/index/"
driver.get(url) 
response=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
```